# Alarm services in android

Tags: android, android-service

in my app I have Getting Data from Url Using AsyncTask, these Url Everyday update some new data, then how is possible to download these data Once in day.

Comment: use push notification.

Comment: I don't think he needs to use the push notification. He can just use the Alarm Manager to schedule a repeating service : https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the **AlarmManager**

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your
>   application code run at a specific time, even if your application is
>   not currently running.

So you can specify a fixed time of the day when you want your data to be updated.

Alternatively, you may use the **TimerTask**   or **Handler**

Comment: You may refer to this blog-post http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android